# Compact complex surface that admits a Kodaira fibration is Kahler

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

A Kodaira fibration is a compact complex surface X endowed with a holomorphic submersion onto a Riemann surface $\pi: X\to\Sigma$ which has connected fibers and is not isotrivial.

Is there an easy way to see why a compact complex surface that admits a Kodaira fibration is Kahler? I know for a complex compact surface is Kahler if and only if its first Betti number is even. I wonder it's possible to deduce that a compact complex surface that admits a Kodaira fibration has even Betti number?

Comment: What is a Kodaira fibration?

Comment: @abx I added a definition

Comment: It depends on what you call easy... A standard result in surface theory is that a surface with a line bundle $L$ such that $c_1(L)^2>0$ is projective. Consider a fiber $F$ of your fibration; its genus $g$ is $\geq 2$, hence by the genus formula $(K_X\cdot F)=2g-2>0$. Then $(K_X+nF)^2>0$ for $n\gg 0$, hence the result.

Comment: @abx Sorry why is $g>1$?

Comment: If $g=1$ the $j$-invariant of the fibers must be constant, hence $X$ is an elliptic fiber bundle. I assumed that you exclude this case — otherwise, as observed by Nick L, you can get non Kähler surfaces.

Comment: All Kodaira fibrations are projective algebraic. This is standard material, see the book by Barth, Hulek, Peters, Van de Ven, beginning of chapter V.14 (same argument as abx, supplemented by the fact that indeed g>1 by Theorem III.15.4)

Comment: @YangMills thank you, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f \colon S \longrightarrow B$ be a Kodaira fibration, and let $F$ be a general fibre. Then by [Kas68, Thm. 1.1] we have $g(B) \geq 2$ and $g(F) \geq 3$.

In particular, $S$ contains no rational or elliptic curves: in fact, such curves cannot neither dominate the base (because $g(B) \geq 2$) nor be contained in fibres (because the fibration is by assumption smooth).

So every Kodaira fibred surface $S$ is minimal and, by the superadditivity of the Kodaira dimension, it is of general type.

In particular, it is not only Kähler  but actually *algebraic* (i.e., projective).

**References.**

[Kas68] A. Kas: [On deformations of a certain type of irregular algebraic surface](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2373484), *American J. Math.* **90**, 789-804 (1968). [ZBL0202.51702](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0202.51702).

Comment: Can you explain the theorem 1.1 of Kas' paper, why the map $U\to T$ is holomorphic?